# yii redirect not working

Tags: php, yii, redirect

In Yii framework `$this->redirect` function not working.

```
class TplUserNavigation extends CWidget{

public function run()
    {
        if(isset(Yii::app()->user->id) && Yii::app()->user->getState('userType') == 'User'){
         $users = Users::model()->findByAttributes(array('id'=>Yii::app()->user->id));
         $this->render('webroot.themes.'.Yii::app()->theme->name.'.views.layouts.tpl_navigation', array('users'=>$users));
        }else{
          $this->redirect('site/index'); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try:

```
$this->redirect("site/index");
```

or if you want to redirect to home page:

```
$this->redirect(Yii::app()->homeUrl);
```

From **CWidget** try:

```
$this->owner->redirect(array("site/index"));
```

Read more [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/40674-redirect-from-widget/) about redirect from widget.

Comment: i have tried that but it error says: redirect do not have closer

Comment: i'm using this function in components.

Comment: @aman you try? `$this->owner->redirect(array("site/index"));`

Comment: @TotPeRo Guide me : what owner will do?

Comment: @YatinMistry : returns the owner/creator of this widget-> the base Controller

Comment: @YatinMistry with pleasure

Comment: Explanation: redirect() is function of CController class so it should be called by CController's object only, directly it can not be called by an object of CWidget. In your case $this->owner is object of controller class in other cases you can use Yii::app()->getController()->redirect(array('controller/action')); Hope this will help to understand the flow.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're just trying to go to the site's index, try something like this:

```
 $this->redirect(Yii::app()->baseUrl);
```

If you want to redirect the user to some other page than the home page try using:

```
 $this->redirect(Yii::app()->createUrl('controlller/action'));
```

This will come handy when you try url rewriting using yii url rules.

Answer (score 2):

```
 $this->redirect(array('site/index'));
```

Comment: At the moment this is a very short and low quality answer. Please expand on your answer and also say why your answer is right.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this, Hope it helps

```
$this->redirect(array('site/index'));
```

You can also try this one..

```
Yii::app()->getController()->redirect(array('/path/to/url'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove array from redirect function

Syntex `$this->redirect(<contoroller>/<action>)`

else try this

```
$this->redirect(Yii::app()->createUrl('controller/action'));
```

Comment: i have tried that but it error says: redirect do not have closer

Comment: i try both but, error says: TplUserNavigation and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "redirect".

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple way (put code before return function and exit()) :

```
header('Location: ' . Url::toRoute('/post/index'));
exit();
return ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$this->redirect(Router::url(array('controller'=>'site', 'action'=>'index')));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->redirect(Yii::app()->createUrl('site/index'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way :

$this->redirect(array('action_name'));

**Example** : $this->redirect(array('view'));

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:
$this->redirect(array(''site/index'));

Answer (score 0):

You can also redirect in **Yii** by using following approach.

```
Yii::app()->getController()->redirect(array('/path/to/url'));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is Yii 1 then:

e.g.

```
    $this->redirect(['route_to_action,GET_PARAMETERS]);
```

Read the manual:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#redirect-detail

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use:

```
$this->redirect
```

from widget, cause in that case $this is for current widget and widget does not have redirect method, and not the controller. What you need is Yii::app()->controller, that will get you active controller instance from any place in Yii, something like :

```
Yii::app()->controller->redirect('site/index');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `$this` is a [CWidget](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWidget), not a [CController](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController). CWidget doesn't have a `redirect` method.

Second, `$this->createUrl` will create an URL relative cu current controller (`$this->owner`).

Use `Yii::app()->createUrl('/site/index')`.

Note the leading `/` before `site` (`createUrl` relative to `baseUrl`, not to current controller).

Answer (score -1):

It could be so that (depending on your project), you would have to use:

`Yii::$app->redirect('site/index');` from the controller.

Answer (score -1):

***1)Redirect Anywhere***

```
Yii::app()->request->redirect(Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl("controller/action"));
```

***2)Redirect Between Controller***

```
 $this->redirect(array("controller/action"));
```